# How to transpose CSV string into rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, string

How to transpose CSV string in rows? In the example below, rows are transposed into CSV string but I would like to do the inverse operation (split this string "Day,Evening,Night" into rows)?. How to do that?

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
-- Check Table Column
SELECT [Name]
FROM HumanResources.Shift
GO
-- Get CSV values
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + s.Name
FROM HumanResources.Shift s
ORDER BY s.Name
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
GO
```

The example is taken from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/21/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column-part-2/).

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques in *the* canonical reference here: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) by Erland Sommarskog

We use the numbers table technique

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using UDF written in C# - relatively easy to develop (if you're familiar with C#) and the fastest choice when it comes to execution.

Reading a reference provided by gbn will give much deeper understanding of the subject, though will certainly take longer.